# Even after + present perfect vs present simple

Tags: grammar, conditionals, present-perfect

I came across the following sentence posted at the city of Melbourne public transportation rules, referring to the duties of the transportation officers:

> They can check your ticket and concession entitlement, even after
>   you’ve left the vehicle or station.

Why the verb in the dependent clause (following `even after`) is in Present Perfect? Would this sentence be grammatically incorrect or possibly have a different meaning when Present Simple were to be used instead, i.e.

> They can check your ticket and concession entitlement, even after
>   you leave the vehicle or station

?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! I can highly recommend [the English Language Lerners Stack Exchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com) for many useful questions regarding topics similar to this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are partially right.

Using the Present Simple Tense is quite correct because there's a special lexical indication of precedence ('even after').

But the Present Perfect Tense is preferable (though optional) here because the Perfect verb form makes the whole sentence stronger, more emphatic.

Compare your example with the sentence where the Present Perfect Tense is obligatory:

They can check your ticket and concession entitlement, ***when*** you have left the vehicle or station.